# Possibility of connecting 2 External Monitors (LCDs) with a laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

I've a laptop with 1366x768 resolution (Nvidia GT720M). Is it possible that I can use 2 external monitors with my laptop. While the 2 external monitors are used I don't want to use the laptop screen. Also, is it possible to have high resolution display on the monitor because my laptop's graphic cards (the other one is intel's) can support full hd display.

Request for more information and I'll provide it for accurate answer.

From my graphic card's specification web page:-

> Able to drive industry’s largest and highest resolution flat-panel
>   displays up to 2560x1600 and with support for High-bandwidth Digital
>   Content Protection (HDCP).

--

Update: December 19, 2014

Thanks [Kristian](https://superuser.com/users/380084/kristian) for the answer. Here are more details. My laptop don't have DisplayPort 1.2. But it do have VGA out and HDMI out. Monitors are still to be bought. I'll make sure they have both VGA and HDMI input. Specifications page:-

http://www.lenovo.com/shop/emea/content/pdf/Essential/BSeries/en/B5400DSEN.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's hard to give a clean-cut answer when we don't know what outputs your laptop has, and what inputs your monitors have.

If your laptop has a DisplayPort 1.2 output, you can daisy-chain two monitors through it. So yes, it's possible. Your graphics card surely has the muscles to run two full-HD monitors, provided your laptop can provide output for both of them somehow.

You could also consider connecting one monitor via HDMI (if your laptop has it) and one via the standard D-SUB (VGA) port (if you have one).

However, I would definitely go with the DisplayPort solution if at all possible.

Note: if you have the monitors already, first step would be to check what inputs they have.

Comment: I am not sure if they can provide separate view or not. Is it always that if we have separate VGA and HDMI out then they both can be used to provide split screen display on 2 external monitors? Or are there any restriction. Just to be more clear I want to have 2 screens with different display, and I can drag things between the screens for my ease.

Comment: You can definitely achieve this out-of-the box using the solution you suggest yourself. Connect 1 monitor via D-SUB (VGA) and another via HDMI. That way you can extend your desktop and have the "2 screens with different display" that you describe. You can just set it up from windows Display Properties as per [this guide](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2406969,00.asp).

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. That was very helpful indeed.